# Error when modifying rules file in debian packaging

Tags: application-development, packaging, debian

Trying to get my debian packaging to work as I want, I modified the debian/rules file (showing line numbers)

```
12 %:
13  dh $@ 
14
15 override_dh_install:
16     dh_install
17     install -m 644 "My Company's Folder" "debian/mainproject/usr/share/MyCompanyFolder"

error:
.....
dpkg-buildpackage: host architecture i386
 dpkg-source --before-build mainproject-1.0
 fakeroot debian/rules clean
debian/rules:16: *** missing separator.  Stop.
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules clean gave error exit status 2
```

Comment: In general, IMO it is best to avoid spaces in file names/directories as they cause issues such as this. Try quoting the file name `mainproject_1/* "/usr/share/My Company's Folder/MainProjector"` or escaping the spaces with a \  `mainproject_1/* /usr/share/My Company's\ Folder/MainProject` . I am not sure if the "'" is going to be a problem as well. Similar advice.

Comment: \040 is for url (apache)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - i have tried both - see my explanation... escaping spaces gave me an error and adding quotes not only gave me an error but created folders " at top and inside... in the debian. Unfortunately the company folder where I have to place this contains spaces... If there is absolutely no way to do this then I will place the product in a folder with no spaces but if i can i want to place the product in the existing company folder.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to do this with spaces. You will have to wait to see if anyone has any other suggestions. The "'" may also be problematic.

Comment: Edited question to remove everything except what is related to last error that I was led to while trying to find an answer...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

For your particular `debian/rules:16: *** missing separator.  Stop.` error, make sure you have tab characters in your `debian/rules` file. Spaces to indent do not work.

Comment: Thank you, the tab in the file took me to the next error... I have to find out what to write to make it do the right thing

Comment: Thanks, that error message is totally unhelpful.